# Can't delete XML file

Tags: php, header, http-headers, cache-control

Background:

My webpage loads entries from an XML file via AJAX/jQuery and displays them (works fine)

The page also has a form that submits via AJAX/jQuery to a PHP file which writes to the XML file, then reloads the XML entries via AJAX/jQuery and displays them (works fine)

I have the following odd problem:

If I delete the XML file through FileZilla, or try to overwrite the XML file by uploading a copy from my local machine, the entries do not change at all when I'm looking at my page. In fact, if overwrite the XML file with a new copy, I see the new copy if I navigate to it in my address bar like: http://mysite.com/myxmlfile.xml, however, in the page that displays the XML entries, the old entries (like the file was never overwritten/deleted) are still displayed!

Confused!

---

Here's my PHP file:

```
<?php

    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Cache: no-cache; must-revalidate;');

    function signGuestbook($entry){

        $date = date("n.d.Y");
        $name = $entry['name'];
        $email = $entry['email'];
        $comment = $entry['comment'];

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $doc->load('guestbook.xml');

        $root = $doc->firstChild;
        $e = $doc->createElement('entry');
        $dateNode = $doc->createElement('date', $date);
        $nameNode = $doc->createElement('name', $name);
        $emailNode = $doc->createElement('email', $email);
        $commentNode = $doc->createElement('comments', $comment);

        $e->appendChild($dateNode);
        $e->appendChild($nameNode);
        $e->appendChild($emailNode);
        $e->appendChild($commentNode);

        $root->appendChild($e);
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        $doc->save('guestbook.xml');
    }

    function loadGuestbook(){

        $gBook = new DOMDocument();
        $gBook->load('guestbook.xml');

        $entries = $gBook->getElementsByTagName('entry');
        $entries_arr = array();

        foreach($entries as $entry)
        {
            $date    = $entry->getElementsByTagName('date')->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $name    = $entry->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $email   = $entry->getElementsByTagName('email')->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $comment = $entry->getElementsByTagName('comments')->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $entries_arr[] = array(
                'date'    => $date,
                'name'    => $name,
                'email'   => $email,
                'comment' => $comment
            );
        }

        return json_encode($entries_arr);
    }

    $entry = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['entry']), true);

    if($entry != null){

        signGuestbook($entry);
    }


    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    echo loadGuestbook();

    ?>
```

Here's my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post('guestbook.php?' + new Date().getTime(), loadGuestbook, "text");
});

function loadGuestbook(gBook){

    var gBookDiv = $('div#guestbook');
    gBookDiv.empty();

    var entries = JSON.parse(gBook);

    $.each(entries, function(i, entry){

        gBookDiv.prepend(
            '<div class="entry">' +
            '<span class="date">' + entries[i].date + '</span>' +
            '<strong class="blue">Name:</strong><span class="name">' + entries[i].name+ '</span><br />' +
            '<strong class="blue">Email:</strong><span class="email">' + entries[i].email + '</span><br />' +
            '<strong class="blue">Comments:</strong><p>' + entries[i].comment + '</p>' +
            '</div>'
        );
    });
}

function signGuestbook(){

    var name    = $('input#name').val();
    var email   = $('input#email').val();
    var comment = $('textarea#comments').val();

    if(name == null || name == '' || email == null || email == ''){
        alert('You must provide a name and email.');
    }

    else{

        var entry = {
            "name"    : name,
            "email"   : email,
            "comment" : comment
        };

        var entryString = JSON.stringify(entry);
        $.post('guestbook.php?' + new Date().getTime(), { entry : entryString }, loadGuestbook, "text");

        $('input#name').val('');
        $('input#email').val('');
        $('textarea#comments').val('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you clear browser cache or might have some server side caching enabled?

Comment: Yes I cleared my browser cache. I don't have server-side cache enabled as far as I know, although that seems like a plausible cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a caching issue. To prevent your Ajax calls from being cached add the time to your Ajax call:

```
$.post('myphp.php?' + new Date().getTime(), { my : dataString }, myFunction, "text");
```

Comment: Or leave PHP out of it entirely `'myxmlfile.xml?' + new Date().getTime()`

Comment: Slight problem, that's not how I'm making my AJAX calls. I'm using $.post('myphp.php', { my : dataString }, myFunction, "text");

Comment: Well then replace `new Ajax.Request('/` with `$.post('`

Comment: No dice. Appending with the date had no effect.

Comment: @Eric In that case, I can only assume you're deleting the wrong XML file or your ISP uses a particularly persistent caching proxy.

Comment: Could you post some code then? I cannot help you further from just the description of your problem. If I see your code maybe I can. E.g. what does myphp.php do exactly?

Comment: It indeed does delete because if I try navigating to it, I get a 404. However, the entries from it are still showing up on the webpage, and I can still add entries via the FORM on the page! It's the only XML file on the darned website, so there is no confusion as to which XML it is.

Comment: Your code looks fine... very strange. Please let us know what was the problem if you DO find out what went wrong.

Comment: @Eric are you 100% sure that the XML file you're deleting / modifying is the same one PHP is using?

Comment: No I'm not, although I can only see one copy of guestbook.xml on my host. So a cache problem is the only thing that seems like a cause.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to add this in your PHP script before sending the XML file:

```
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache: no-cache; must-revalidate;');
```

Comment: I'm not actually sending the XML file, the XML file is manipulated via PHP, and JSON is sent back. But I've tried your suggestion adding the headers, and the one above appending the date, but to no avail...